# How do you manage Bootstrap LESS files for a responsive website?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, less

This is a generic question. I'm building a website with Bootstrap that must be responsive. I'd like to know what is the "standard" procedure working on LESS/css.

First, you create css rules for a standard site (for desktop display)? 
Secondly, you add specific rules for smartphone or tablet in the appropriate LESS files (`responsive-767px-max.less`, etc)?

The problem is that there are many rules that must be **common** for desktop and smartphone display! Then I should copy these rules in every `responsive-xxx.less` files. I think this is not too confortable. Maybe the common rules must be written in `bootstrap.less`, below the @import rules?

In short, I'm curious to know how you manage these things.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, Responsive is more bottom-up than what you describe.

1. First, you make sure your site/app works in the most barebones browser, with minimal support of CSS and JS.
2. Then you build up from there, adding "icing" with greater browser capabilities and window size.

It also about not *just* using the breakpoints, but also making some things scale sensible in size, width, height, as the window is resized.

In practice, just by using Bootstrap, you're gaining the above capabilities. You shouldn't have to do too much more other than make some decisions in the media queries for certain components to show or hide, like you describe.

- Include the responsive stylesheet
- Use the fluid versions of containers and rows, like:

Here's the relevant Bootstrap docs:

- http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive
- http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html